# Exception has occurred. RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0). index error

Tags: flutter, dart

When I debug and run my codes, there is an error pops up regarding the index.
I got this error as the uploaded image here.
[image]

here are my codes:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:meals_recipes/models/meal.dart';

import 'package:meals_recipes/screens/categories_screen.dart';
import 'package:meals_recipes/screens/favorites_screen.dart';
import 'package:meals_recipes/widgets/main_drawer.dart';

class TabsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Meal> favoriteMeals;

  TabsScreen(this.favoriteMeals);

  @override
  State<TabsScreen> createState() => _TabsScreenState();
}

class _TabsScreenState extends State<TabsScreen> {
  List<Map<String, Object>> _pages = [];
  int _selectedPageIndex = 0;

  void _selectPage(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _pages = [
        {'page': CategoriesScreen(), 'title': 'Categories'},
        {
          'page': FavoritesScreen(widget.favoriteMeals),
          'title': 'Your Favorites'
        }
      ];
      _selectedPageIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(_pages[_selectedPageIndex]['title'] as String),
      ),

  drawer: MainDrawer(),
  body: _pages[_selectedPageIndex]['page'] as Widget,
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    onTap: _selectPage,
    items: [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.category), label: 'Categories'),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.star), label: 'Favorites'),
    ],
    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
    unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
    selectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
    currentIndex: _selectedPageIndex,
    //type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
  ),
);
}
}
```

Please help me out.
thanks in advance.
How can I remove the 'title' index? should I add a number instead?
I have no idea about this issue!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you create `_TabsScreenState`, `_pages` is empty until the `_selectPage(..)` method is run and _pages gets a value.

you should handle this before you are trying get value from emptiness. as an option, you could set values to you _pages list in the init state method:

```
    class _TabsScreenState extends State<TabsScreen> {
      late final List<Map<String, Object>> _pages;
      int _selectedPageIndex = 0;

     @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _pages = [
            {'page': CategoriesScreen(), 'title': 'Categories'},
            {
              'page': FavoritesScreen(widget.favoriteMeals),
              'title': 'Your Favorites'
            }
          ];
      }
    
      void _selectPage(int index) {
        setState(() {
          _selectedPageIndex = index;
        });
      }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(_pages[_selectedPageIndex]['title'] as String),
      ),

  drawer: MainDrawer(),
  body: _pages[_selectedPageIndex]['page'] as Widget,
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    onTap: _selectPage,
    items: [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.category), label: 'Categories'),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.star), label: 'Favorites'),
    ],
    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
    unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
    selectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
    currentIndex: _selectedPageIndex,
    ...
  ),
    ...
```

Comment: do not understand? where should I put this code line?

Comment: Ok, but the same error will then be appeared for this line: body: _pages[_selectedPageIndex]['page'] as Widget,

Comment: ok, I get it. you need to set values to the list. check answer